# Dreamweaver automatically escape quotes?

Tags: escaping, dreamweaver, quotes

I'm trying to escape quotes in a large HTML template. Is there any way to make Dreamweaver do this, or a website on the internet to run it through, so I just get \ before my "s? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ctrl+f and search for " and replace with \"

Comment: OK I am officially dumb. That makes sense -  so obvious. thanks!